# What is the difference between generics and dynamic in dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

Let me introduce the errors why I got this issue. ([Detail here](https://github.com/ianldgs/material_search/issues/11))

```dart
type '(String, String) => bool' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic, String) => bool'
```

This is the error from [material_search](https://github.com/ianldgs/material_search), and the [solution](https://github.com/ianldgs/material_search/commit/64405dedafe8eba8765a591111e455a71bc4827a) is:

```dart
   - _filter(T v, String c) {
   + _filter(dynamic v, String c) {
   - onSelect: (T value) => Navigator.of(context).pop(value),
   + OnSelect: (dynamic value) => Navigator.of(context).pop(value),
```

Changing all of generics type `T` to dynamic, and The issue seems to be happened when dart 2 is appearing.

So, I got these question here,

1. What is the difference between **generics** and **dynamic** in dart?
2. What's the limit that **only works with generics** or on the other hand? In the above issue, this is **only works with dynamic**.

**Edit:**
Let me provide a simple example to make question more clear:

#### Define a class with genetic

```dart
typedef bool GeneticFunction<T>(T geneticData, String key);

class Component<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  Component({this.geneticFunc});
  final GeneticFunction<T> geneticFunc;

  @override
  _componentState<T> createState() => _componentState<T>();
}
```

#### One of the method is working below

#1

```dart
    Component<CoolType>(
      geneticFunc: (CoolType cool, String keyword){
        return false;
      },
    );
```

#2

```dart
    Component<CoolType>(
      geneticFunc: (dynamic cool, String keyword){
        return false;
      },
    );
```

The answer **#2** is working, and It means I **don't even need generic**, just go **dynamic**. If you use **#1**, there is sometimes even no error in runtime, and you might stuck at there whole day.

There is an official discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flutter-dev/vWtwyv63Kao), said that **T** would always be **dynamic** in runtime, so **#2** is the only choosen.

In the conclusion, I have no idea when to use **generic**, and seems to be **always use dynamic** now, because of the result above.

Comment: Could you provide the call that resulted in this error: `type '(String, String) => bool' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic, String) => bool'`? I see the fix, but to see the call to `_filter` I would have to recreate the error here: https://github.com/ianldgs/material_search/issues/11

Comment: @GazihanAlankus, I thought my latest example code is the same idea, because I simplify my `filter` function there :P

Comment: @GazihanAlankus, In the `_componentState`, override a simple **initState**, and called `print("the test one");  var a = widget.geneticFunc;  print("the test two");`. You could find the error between test two and test one.

Comment: Both #1 and #2 seem to work for me in DartPad (after removing flutter stuff). https://dartpad.dartlang.org/8e054e39063362a360f1b376ab4d6f95 If you can create a code with error I would love to help. The reason for using generics is to have type safety. You can do everything dynamic but you're no better than JavaScript then.

Comment: You should see what `MaterialSearchResult` gets as its type argument over here: https://github.com/ianldgs/material_search/blob/77a55c37da45d88cf827064dbd0566689467e56e/lib/material_search.dart#L146 You can set a breakpoint there to do that. `MaterialSearchResult<T>` is probably getting a T that is not compatible with the T of `MaterialSearch<T>`.

Comment: @GazihanAlankus, This is only happend in flutter **StatefulWidget**, I paste the code [here](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/8e054e39063362a360f1b376ab4d6f95). Please read this!

Comment: Your edits to the DartPad are not saved, it reflects this gist: https://gist.github.com/gazialankus/8e054e39063362a360f1b376ab4d6f95

Comment: Sorry, I have never used It before, let me use [pastbin](https://pastebin.com/M5rbFKsY) for now.

Comment: pastebin is blocked for me unfortunately

Comment: post it on [gist](https://gist.github.com/Tokenyet/5e9bb507096819b4da69c551efd0ef8f) for you.

Comment: @Tokenyet, generic class is something that we want to be reusable between different types.

Comment: this question should have an answer. @Tokenyet did you get the right answer?

Comment: @Jorge, Thanks for reminding me I posted this issue in the past :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the long delay for my question, the real problem for this issue is **What is the correct way to use generic with StatefulWidget?**

Let's see the original code:

```
class Component<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  Component({this.data, this.geneticFunc});
  final T data;
  final GeneticFunction<T> geneticFunc;
  void test()
  {
    var testFunc = geneticFunc;
    testFunc(data, "123");
  }

  @override
  _ComponentState<T> createState() {
    return _ComponentState<T>();
  }
}

class _ComponentState<T> extends State<Component>
{
  @override
  void initState() {
    print("test one");
    var a = widget.geneticFunc;
    print("test two");
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(width: 20, height: 20,);
  }
}
```

Guess what? just remember to add a `<T>` when extending a generic class, and the problem sloved.

```
class _ComponentState<T> extends State<Component<T>>
```

So the issue `type '(String, String) => bool' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic, String) => bool'` will never bother me again.

And the following code should work now.

```
Component<CoolType>(
  geneticFunc: (CoolType a, String key){
    return false;
  },
)
```